# Raspberry Pi as prototype wearable tech?

Tags: wifi, bluetooth, web

I want to create a measure using javascript/php in a web app. Not using my Raspberry Pi. Ultimately, I want to deliver said measure as a variable to wearable technology (watches). I want the measure to be represented by the dial on a watch.

I'd need wifi to link to the web app and some code to direct the variable (what language?)..

Could the raspberry pi be used to create a prototype of the required technology (of course not used as wearable tech). I'm just trying  to figure out how I would approach such a problem - how I would create it from scratch?

What would be my starting steps on the pi if possible to create a prototype?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this I advise not using the Pi at all.  You're going to want a small-sized micro-controller for the real application, which will require a different type of program.  If you go the route of the Pi, you'll end-up with a lot of stuff that doesn't port over, and maybe a little bit of stuff that does. This will almost surely take you down a path that's more like Arduino than it is like Raspberry Pi.

Adafruit (just as an example - I'm not affiliated) has a whole section on "wearables" that includes small micro-controllers and tutorials on how to use them.  I'd start there (www.adafruit.com). Even if you end up buying from someone else, this will help you get a survey.

Comment: To add to this, Unless you are planning on using embedded linux, which is likely overkill for your application. Using an RPI for prototyping would be a dead end for two reasons. 1. Its not easy to run baremetal code on the RPI platform due to proprietary  firmware 2. When you are out of prototype phase, the MOQ for broadcom is at least $100,000 and you don't get a datasheet until you commit to that amount. You can certainly develop a Proof Of Concept, but not a prototype. RPI is a mini-computer and not a prototyping platform.

Comment: Does a forum like this exist for Adafruit?! I see lots of resources on their website, so I'll start there! Thanks

Comment: Adafruit is a retailer. I think they have their own user support forum somewhere. They do some "breakout boards" to make stuff more accessible, but they are ultimately re-selling other company's hardware. Once you settle on a controller, you'll need to start digging into the resources available for its original manufacturer.